# How to print lines where it matchs specific number in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cat

I have a text file called file.txt like below,

```
01_ABC_0000  AA
02_CDE_0000  BB
03_EFG_0000  CC
04_ABC_0001  DD
05_CDE_0001  EE
06_EFG_0001  FF
```

where it should separated into two different files, like
file0.txt

```
01_ABC_0000  AA
02_CDE_0000  BB
03_EFG_0000  CC
```

and file1.txt

```
04_ABC_0001  DD
05_CDE_0001  EE
06_EFG_0001  FF
```

what i have been trying,
 `cat file00.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/.*\(....\)/\1/')` to get the only numbers from first word but I am not able use this to go forward separating it into the two files.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry, I have edited the question where the first field is `01_ABC_0000` something like this, If I use field separator as underscore it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Seems much cleaner to have those lines that match `0000` go to file 0, the lines that match `0001` go to file 1, etc.

Comment: will the input always be sorted by the last 4 digits of the 1st word/field?

Comment: @markp-fuso yes, it is always sorted by the last four digits of the first word/field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Considering your entries are sorted with values of 2nd column(0000, 00001 and so on). With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk -v count="1" -F'_| +' '
prev!=$2{
  count++
  close(outputFile)
  outputFile=("file"count".txt")
  prev=$2
}
{
  print > (outputFile)
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `sort` + `awk` combination solution in case entries are not sorted.

```
awk -F'_| +' '{print $2,$0}' Input_file | 
sort -nk1                               | 
awk -v count="1" -F'_| +' '
{
  sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
}
prev!=$2{
  count++
  close(outputFile)
  outputFile=("file"count".txt")
  prev=$2
}
{
  print > (outputFile)
}
'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to do this for 2 numbers, you can use

```
cat file00.txt | grep "_0000" >> file1.txt
cat file00.txt | grep "_0001" >> file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'[_ ]' '{print $0 > "file"substr($2,4,1)".txt"}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this with `awk` is something like:

```
awk '{outfile = sprintf("file%d.txt", $2 + 1); print > outfile}' FS='[_ ]' input
```

The manner in which you parse out the relevant number to use will change with the input format.  Also, as the input file grows larger you may to worry about running out of resources, so you might want to close the files explictly with something like:

```
awk '{outfile = sprintf("file%d.txt", $2 + 1); print >> outfile; close(outfile)}' FS='[_ ]' input
```

Which requires you to add some additional logic to ensure that the files are empty or do not exist before you begin.

Comment: is there a way if the first field contains data like 01_ABC_0000, then the field separator doesn't work as expected. I hadn't thought that way, sorry.

Comment: @Wh0r00t You could use `split` and check each element of the array to find which (if any) matches a string of digits.  But if every line contains that format (eg, it is always 2 underscores), just use `$3`

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
num=$(sort -t'_' -k2 file00.txt | sed -n '$s/[^_]*_\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p')
for ((i=0;i<=num;i++)); do
    sed -n "/0\+$i\b/p" file00.txt >> file$i.txt
done
```

Which produces the following output

```
$ head file*
==> file0.txt <==
ABC_0000  AA
CDE_0000  BB
EFG_0000  CC

==> file1.txt <==
ABC_0001  DD
CDE_0001  EE
EFG_0001  FF
```

Comment: is there a way if the first field contains data like 01_ABC_0000, then the field separator doesn't work as expected. I hadn't thought that way, sorry.

Comment: @Wh0r00t If you change the `num` variable, the script will still give the expected output. `num=$(sed -n '$s/\([^_]*_\)\{1,\}\([^ ]*\).*/\2/p' file00.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

```
total 4
-rw-r--r--  1 501  20  96 Jun 14 00:49 inputfile.txt
```

|

```
 # 2nd FS choice if you're VERY certain the format is fixed
 
 {m,g}awk '{ print >("file"$(NF-!_)".txt") }' FS='^[^_]+_[^_]+_|[ \t]+[^ \t]+$'
                                              FS=' .+$|.+_'

total 12
-rw-r--r--  1 501  20  48 Jun 14 00:52 file0000.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 501  20  48 Jun 14 00:52 file0001.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 501  20  96 Jun 14 00:49 inputfile.txt
 

==> file0000.txt <==
01_ABC_0000  AA
02_CDE_0000  BB
03_EFG_0000  CC

==> file0001.txt <==
04_ABC_0001  DD
05_CDE_0001  EE
06_EFG_0001  FF
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU uniq and csplit):

```
uniq -s4 -w4 --group file | csplit --supp -f file -b '%02d.txt' - '/^$/' '{*}'
```

Use uniq to separate each group of lines by an empty line, where groups are determined by skipping the first 4 characters and matching on the following 4.

Pass the output from the above into csplit.

Suppress the matching lines (blank lines) and split the groups into files named `file` and suffix of `%02d.txt` where `%02` is replaced by `00`, `01` `...`.

Alternative using cat and sed:

```
cat -n file | 
sed -En 'H;1h;$!d;x
         s/^\s+(\S+).*_(\S+).*/\1 \2/mg
         s/(\S+) (\S+)\n.*(\S+) \2\n?/\1,\3w file\2.txt\n/gp' | 
sed -nf - file
```

Creates a sed script with the ranges and file number from the original data and then runs the script against the data.